# Which applications are using location service?

Tags: android, location

I found that location service drain my battery. But I think it is not because location service  is ON, it is because some application use that service a lot. Is there any way to find, which application set location service wrong (with high load)? Can I get list of application using location service right now?
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: This question is related to programming/software development. I need to programmatically find, what application is overloading location service.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there are no easy way to get the list of app accessing LocationProvider. But a simple way to diagnose is to kill App who request ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION/ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission one by one.

Many app get location data through call backs like onLocationChanged(...), this make it almost impossible to identify your problem without modifying the Android system. You can modify the location service to record the uid(through Binder.getCallingUid()) to get the current app that using location service. It is not very difficult but heavy-weighted.

EDIT:

There is a LocationManagerService.java under frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server.

In general, there are several ways to get location in Android according to its [Location Strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) .

**LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates**

You can look at the implementation of this in LocationManagerService.java. The method receive an ILocationListener(Binder object) from the client and call this listener later if it receives a location update.

```
@Override
public void requestLocationUpdates(LocationRequest request, ILocationListener listener,
        PendingIntent intent, String packageName) {
    if (request == null) request = DEFAULT_LOCATION_REQUEST;
    checkPackageName(packageName);
    int allowedResolutionLevel = getCallerAllowedResolutionLevel();
    checkResolutionLevelIsSufficientForProviderUse(allowedResolutionLevel,
            request.getProvider());
    LocationRequest sanitizedRequest = createSanitizedRequest(request, allowedResolutionLevel);

    final int pid = Binder.getCallingPid();
    final int uid = Binder.getCallingUid();
    Receiver recevier = checkListenerOrIntent(listener, intent, pid, uid, packageName);

    // providers may use public location API's, need to clear identity
    long identity = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
    try {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            requestLocationUpdatesLocked(sanitizedRequest, recevier, pid, uid, packageName);
        }
    } finally {
        Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(identity);
    }
}
```

Basically, you can get the uid of the application in this method to know how many apps are requesting location updates. But you should also remember to look at the removeUpdates method.

**LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation**

You can also log out the uid of the application in the implementation of this method.

After modifying the code, you can compile the whole Android project, install your application, and get your result.

Comment: Ok, thank you for advice, I will try to kill method, but I am a little  afraid of that app can start it again and again and it could be hard to find it if I don´t want to uninstall all these application (also some applications is not possible to uninstall).

Could you clarify a little how I could modify location service? I am not sure I follow.

Comment: Generally that app will not get started if no intents(not broadcast) send to it. For modifying location service, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to implement this : )

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean something like services running in the background and use GPS? So that you don't activate the GPS yourself but it's still running?
In that case there's no way I know to get all Apps that are allowed to use GPS in background.
You can go to your Settings->Apps and check the permissions which apps are allowed to use GPS.

A typicall background GPS user is the facebook app (or google+ I guess).
Hope this helps.

Edit: Alternativly you could disable GPS when you don't need it so that no app has the possibility to use it in background.

Comment: I see and you are right, I can do that (except turn off GPS, because I need it), but I am more interesting about finding resource of problem programmatically, because according my experience some application ignore what I set (typically Facebook). It means I can´t be sure that setting is working : ( Anyway thank you for your inside.

Comment: I guess if you turn the GPS off in your settings the hardware part of your device gets switched off (or at least I hope so). So even Facebook in its stupidity shouldn't be able to connect.